# passing value of dropdownlist to textbox using mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing values of dropdown to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070637/passing-values-of-dropdown-to-textbox)

I have got a dropdownlist, a submit button and a textbox in my view.  I want to pass the selected value of dropdownlist to the textbox when the submit button is clicked or onChange event of dropdownlist. How can I achieve this????

**Edit**:

I did this but it didn't not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ddlComp').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue);
        });
    }); 
</script>

<form action="/">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlcomp", Model.CompanyList)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    @Html.TextBox("txtCompName")
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit, the id of your drop down list does not line up with that of your jQuery selector. Based upon your form it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ddlcomp').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mydropdown").change(function(){     
  $("#mytextbox").val($(this).value());
});
```

Comment: I did like this but not worked.   @model ddlself.Models.dropself

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#ddlComp').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue);
    });
});
</script>
<form action="/">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlcomp", Model.CompanyList)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />    
    @Html.TextBox("txtCompName")
</form>

Comment: add code in question not readable here