# passing values of dropdown to textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have got a dropdownlist, a submit button and a textbox in my view. I want to pass the selected value of dropdownlist to the textbox when the submit button is clicked or onChange event of dropdownlist. How can I achieve this????

I solved it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#ddlComp').change(function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue);
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlcomp", Model.CompanyList)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />    
    @Html.TextBox("txtCompName")
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused, have you solved it yourself? Or are you saying that is what you have tried?

Comment: If that solved your problem, please post it as an answer to your own question and marked it as solved (I think available in a couple of days if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to pass the selected value of dropdownlist to the textbox **when
>   the submit button is clicked or onChange event of dropdownlist**

```
$(function() {
    var selectedValue = ''; // declare variable here

    // on drop down change
    $('#ddlComp').change(function() {
        selectedValue = $(this).val(); // store value in variable
        $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue); // update on change
    });

    // on submit button click
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        $('#txtCompName').val(selectedValue); // update on submit button
    });
});
```